# Can I use toLocaleString() to truncate a number without rounding?

Tags: javascript, deno

I would like to truncate `9.95` to `9.9` using `toLocaleString()`. The problem is that `toLocaleString()` always rounds the number to `10.0`.

```
>> (9.95).toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumFractionDigits: 1, maximumFractionDigits: 1})
"10.0"
>> (9.95).toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumFractionDigits: 1, maximumFractionDigits: 1, roundingMode: "trunc"})
"10.0"
```

I want to use it for Deno but the question is about the javascript API not only about Deno. Am I doing something wrong?.

I'm using this in my script `(9.95).toString().substring(0,3)` because the rounding problem.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed maybe useful?

Comment: Note that the number 9.95 does not round to 9.9 when following the JS rules for rounding, it rounds up to 10 [because 0.5 (at any decimal place) rounds up](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-math.round). The code is doing exactly what it should be doing here. If you want different rounding behaviour, you'll have to write your own rounding code.

Comment: @CollinD `toFixed` may not always round as expected. For instance `2.35.toFixed(1)` will give `2.4` but `2.55.toFixed(1)` will give `2.5` because some decimals can't be represented exactly in binary

Comment: well isn't that just frustrating. thanks for correcting :D

Comment: @CollinD And that it seems to work for 9.95 in Op's favor is more a "bug" (not really, but rather unexpected on first glance) than a feature

Comment: `parseInt(9.95 * 10)/10`

Comment: I don't see there is a `roundingMode` field in the options of [`Number.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString). Are you looking for [NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat)?

Answer (score 0):

I see no mention of a `roundingMode` in [ECMAScript® 2023 Language Specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/) nor in [ECMAScript® 2023 Internationalization API Specification](https://tc39.es/ecma402/). I do not believe there is a way to do this with `Number.prototype.toLocaleString` nor with the more advanced `Intl.NumberFormat.prototype.format`.

You can however use some math with [`Math.trunc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc):

```
>> Math.trunc(9.95 * 10) / 10
9.9
```

Which you can then convert to a string, etc.